# modify keyboard layout locally

Tags: x11, keyboard

I haven't found the correct keyboard layout for my macbook pro yet.
I've found one that looks like it though (in `.xinitrc`):

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant mac
```

yet this has one difference: the `(',~)` key and the `(§,±)` keys are switched. I've always managed this by editing the corresponding file in §/etc/share/X11/xkb`but it is a drag to have to do this everytim`X11` updgrades.

Can it be done from a local file e.g. `.xinitrc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you want is `.xmodmap` Have a look at `man xmodmap` for details on how to set it up.

xmodmap uses the physical keycodes to make the change. You can get those from `xev`. Launch it, then tap the appropriate keys and see what keycode number pops up.

You should only need two lines in your .xmodmap, both of them looking something like

```
keycode 49 = grave asciicircum
keycode 15 = <whichever keys are activated in first-level> section plusminus
```

Those two keycodes, by the way, are wild guesses and probably wrong.